# Issues with pagination of a html table generated with a php script

Tags: php, html

I'm handling a php code that reads a .csv file inside the same folder and print a table in html.
As the file contains a lot of rows, i'd like to limit the table to a specific number of rows (for example 50).
I really don't know how to do, anyone can help a newbie as i'm?

```
 <?php

 $row = 1;
 if (($handle = fopen("myfile.csv", "r")) !== FALSE) {

echo '<table border="1">';

while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ";")) !== FALSE) {
    $num = count($data);
    if ($row == 1) {
        echo '<thead><tr>';
    }else{
        echo '<tr>';
    }

    for ($c=0; $c < $num; $c++) {
        if(empty($data[$c])) {
           $value = "&nbsp;";
        }else{
           $value = $data[$c];
        }
        if ($row == 1) {
            echo '<th>'.$value.'</th>';
        }else{
            echo '<td>'.$value.'</td>';
        }
    }

    if ($row == 1) {
        echo '</tr></thead><tbody>';
    }else{
        echo '</tr>';
    }
    $row++;
}

echo '</tbody></table>';
fclose($handle);
 }
 ?>
```

Comment: jQuery DataTables: http://www.datatables.net

Comment: You will just use $row++.  Learn a bit more about control structures and give it a try!

Comment: Do you want pagination (like Google search results)?  Or do you just want to limit the display of results?  There are two answers posted, and which answer you use will depend on this.

Comment: Thx for your reply Smandoli, the pagination i want is exactly like Google search! Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

what you will want to do is pass in a GET parameter, something like start, and then use that to set the starting number for your for loop

```
for ($c=0; $c < $num; $c++) {
```

then becomes something like

```
for ($c=$_GET['start']; $c < $_GET['start']+50 && $c < $num; $c++) {
```

then at the bottom of the page you add links like

```
<a href="<?=$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']?>?start=<?=$_GET['start']-50 ?>">"><< Prev</a>
<a href="<?=$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']?>?start=<?=$_GET['start']+50 ?>">">Next >></a>
```

obviously this is not a robust/secure solution, you'll need to add checks to make sure that the start variable is a number, and add bounds checking.

Comment: Hi Peter, I tried to use your codes but nothing happened, maybe i mistaked something... anyway thanks for your kind reply

Answer (score 1):

You can use `$row`'s value to limit it.

The code would look something like this:

```
if ($row == 50):
    break; //exits while loop
endif;
```

Comment: `($row >= 50)` will be safer because `$row` will immediately try to find ways to not equal 50.  :-)